# inconsistent R-squared values in lm()

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am fitting the same linear model in two different ways, resulting in the same parameter estimates but differing R-squared values.  Where does the difference come from?  Is this a bug in R?  Here is my code:

```
m1 <- lm(stack.loss ~ ., data = stackloss)
summary(m1)

X <- model.matrix(m1)
y <- stackloss$stack.loss
m2 <- lm(y ~ 0 + X)
summary(m2)
```

The output for `m1` is the following (slightly shortened):

```
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -39.9197    11.8960  -3.356  0.00375 ** 
Air.Flow      0.7156     0.1349   5.307  5.8e-05 ***
Water.Temp    1.2953     0.3680   3.520  0.00263 ** 
Acid.Conc.   -0.1521     0.1563  -0.973  0.34405    

Residual standard error: 3.243 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9136,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8983 
F-statistic:  59.9 on 3 and 17 DF,  p-value: 3.016e-09
```

The output for `m2` is has the same estimates for coefficients and residual standard error, but different R-squared values and different F-statistic:

```
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
X(Intercept) -39.9197    11.8960  -3.356  0.00375 ** 
XAir.Flow      0.7156     0.1349   5.307  5.8e-05 ***
XWater.Temp    1.2953     0.3680   3.520  0.00263 ** 
XAcid.Conc.   -0.1521     0.1563  -0.973  0.34405    

Residual standard error: 3.243 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.979, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9741 
F-statistic: 198.2 on 4 and 17 DF,  p-value: 5.098e-14
```

Why are the R-squared values different?

Comment: you should check this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term-increases-r2-in-linear-mo

Comment: You included an intercept, but it's not in the default name, so lm() interprets it as the intercept is missing and uses another way to calculate the r squared

Comment: The correct r-squared is with m1

Comment: @StupidWolf, please post as answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term-increases-r2-in-linear-mo) and [also this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486090/why-does-r-squared-change-with-a-no-intercept-model). Here's a break down of what is happening in the [lm()](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/lm.R#L302) source code. The relevant part:

```
r <- z$residuals
f <- z$fitted.values
w <- z$weights
if (is.null(w)) {
        mss <- if (attr(z$terms, "intercept"))
            sum((f - mean(f))^2) else sum(f^2)
        rss <- sum(r^2)
}
```

Although you included an intercept, the attributes of the terms are not set to include an intercept, compare:

```
attr(m1$terms,"intercept")
[1] 1

attr(m2$terms,"intercept")
[1] 0
```

I do not advise doing this, because you can easily use the formula interface to fit the model, without providing the model matrix yourself. But you can see by changing the attribute, you can get `summary.lm` to use the correct rss and get the correct r-squared:

```
attr(m2$terms,"intercept") = 1
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + X)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.2377 -1.7117 -0.4551  2.3614  5.6978 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
X(Intercept) -39.9197    11.8960  -3.356  0.00375 ** 
XAir.Flow      0.7156     0.1349   5.307  5.8e-05 ***
XWater.Temp    1.2953     0.3680   3.520  0.00263 ** 
XAcid.Conc.   -0.1521     0.1563  -0.973  0.34405    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.243 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9136,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8983 
F-statistic:  59.9 on 3 and 17 DF,  p-value: 3.016e-09
```

Comment: The reason I'm not using the formula interface is that I am programmatically selecting which inputs to include.  For the matrix, I just remove unneeded columns.  For the formula I'm not sure how to remove terms.

Comment: not very sure about your situation, but you can always exclude the intercept from the model matrix, e.g, lm(y ~ 0 + X[,-1]) or use `reformulate` to build your model

Comment: Thanks.  The "situation" is here: https://seehuhn.github.io/MATH3714/S14-methods.html#exm:qsar-search .  In the end I decided to only consider models which include an intercept, just to avoid this complication.

Answer (score 0):

StupidWolf gave you the answer. You are estimating two different regression models.

Because your second model specification m2 <- lm(y ~ 0 + X). You are not estimating an intercept and you have a extra variable variable X(intercept).

To get the same R^2 just correct the model

```
m1 <- lm(stack.loss ~ ., data = stackloss)
summary(m1)

X <- model.matrix(m1)
y <- stackloss$stack.loss
m2 <- lm(y ~ X)
summary(m2)
```

Gives you the same R^2 since you regress the same model.

Comment: I see that now the $R^2$ values are right again, but now `m2` has *two* intercepts, the one from the matrix $X$ and the one R added itself.  This still does not seem optimal.

Comment: Your original data has four variable, on the second regression you're getting the independent variables from the fist regression, thus you also get a extra variable intercept from the result of your first regression. You can correct this with `m2 <- lm(y ~ X[,-1])`.